# Failed to download packages from Maven repository for Maven project in the IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, download

I've tried to download package in pom.xml file in the Maven but it is always failed to download.
Got the error message:
Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/5/oss-parent-5.pom

I've tried to check the issue, go to the: File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools >Maven >Repositories
URL: https://repo.maven.apache.org.maven2
Type: Remote
Updated: Error
I am not sure if the issue in the Repositories causes issue that can't download package from maven.
Could you show me to fix it?
I'm using IntelliJ Idea 2021.1.1, created maven project.

Comment: Check the [idea.log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory) file while the issue is reproduced. It should contain more detailed info

Comment: Thanks @KonstantinAnnikov. I will check it.